# App will not show first view on device (does not crash either), but works perfectly in simulator. Also loads different icon for device

Tags: ios

I have a program that recently just started not working in the device, but works perfectly in the simulator. There is no crash or errors, but when using the device, it will not load the first view. I have a movie that I run in the beginning, and that runs fine on both simulator and device, but then simulator will bring up the first view and device will not. Black screen.

The other odd thing is that the icon for the app is different on the device than the one on the simulator. The one on the simulator is the correct icon for the app. I did review others with a similar issue, but everything I found revolved around errors and crashing, which mine is not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try removing apps from simulator & device & then run from xCode. Also make sure the images you load are accessed in case-sensitive manner.

Comment: Other details or code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need to watch for is misnamed image files.  By that, I mean uppercase, lowercase issues.  The simulator can't tell the difference between yourpic.png and YourPic.png, but the real devices can.  They will not display art that is misnamed, even though it works fine on the simulator.

You likely have other issues, but you should at least check this one.

Comment: Ok, I definitely have other issues, but determining that I had 2 icon files helped. I noticed that in my info.plist there was no entry for Icon file - I added that and pointed to my icon.png and then removed the icon@2x.png file which is the incorrect one that was showing up. Now the correct icon shows on the device, but I'm still not getting the first view to show up. Is there a setting I'm missing that tells Xcode to use one set of rules for a device and another for simulator? What other info can I provide that would help solve this?

Comment: Does your version of the simulator match up with the OS version on the device you are trying?

Comment: HalR, That's absolutely the issue. My phone is 6.0.1 and I have been testing on the simulator using iPhone 5.1. Hopefully, I can figure out how to remedy that as I need it to work with all versions of the iPhone. I appreciate your help very much. If you have a link on hand for the help I need please, respond, otherwise. Thank you, again!

Comment: Figured out how to update base SDK as well to latest version. Should be good.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some files are missing from your project. They exist in your directories on your computer, so everything runs fine in simulator, but they are not being copied to your device. Check the list of files on the left side of XCode, especially your Resources directory.

You can also check in your build process. Click the target (that's your top level group in your file navigator at the left of XCode). Click the Build Phases tab. Expand "Copy Bundle Resources". Make sure that there aren't any files you need missing from there.